# FBX Export with higher subdivision than what's displayed in blender

Tags: export, subdivision-surface, .fbx, unreal-engine

Is there a way to FBX export a model with higher subdivision than what's displayed in blender?

Comment: Is there a special reason why you cannot simply increase the subdivision levels, export the model and decrease the levels again afterwards?

Comment: The performance in Blender is simply too bad when increasing the SubD so that the model has millions of triangles. The iteration times becomes too slow on huge models.

Comment: Yeah, I mean but, just for a short moment to export it...?

Comment: Problem is that just increasing the SubD to the level I want makes Blender freeze for some time or crash.